# Algebra book that covers algebras

Tags: book-recommendation, algebras

I'm looking for a good algebra book that covers algebras. We are currently using Rotman's Advanced Modern Algebra for my algebra class, but unfortunately it only covers algebras as a subtopic of modules. In class we are covering algebras as a separate topic, and we haven't done module theory yet. The lecturer is working off his own notes for algebras, and they are, let's say, *less than clear*.

The topics we have covered / will cover are basically Frobenius' theorem for classifying the finite-dimensional division algebras over $\mathbb R$ and a lot of smaller results about the nilradical and prime radical.

I would like a recommendation for a book that covers algebras as a separate topic, preferably without basing it on module theory, that I can use to revise for my preliminary exams at the end of the summer.

EDIT: This is the proof of Frobenius' theorem from our notes, to give you an idea of how we are working with algebras:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I fear that the treatment of algebras is deeply entwined with the treatment of modules, even more so than with rings and groups.

Comment: @A.P. That's the impression I get from the couple of books I looked at in the library. We're covering modules immediately after algebras, which seems to be really rare. I'm hoping someone here knows of a book that does the same.

Comment: @A.P. You are absolutely correct. Fixed it :)

Comment: Can you link to your lecturer's notes, by chance? Those would give us an idea of how those results are treated in your course. For example, Frobenius's theorem is covered in Rotman's book (theorem 7.128, page 607 in the AMS edition), but I guess your lecturer considered that too hard for your level.

Comment: @A.P. They are handwritten and he copies them and hands them out to us (he's nearly 75 and doesn't internet). When I go in tomorrow I could scan a some of it (maybe the proof of Frobenius' theorem) and add to my question though.

Comment: 238+ hand-written pages? Your professor is a beast!

Comment: @pjs36 He's amazing, and most of the notes are amazing. It's just that this particular section isn't working for me. We're trying to convince him to turn them into a book.

Comment: Is [this paper](http://www.math.cmu.edu/~wn0g/noll/qu1.pdf) akin to what you're looking for? It doesn't contain results about radical ideals, but section 7 has a proof of Frobenius's theorem along the lines of the notes you posted.

Answer (score 0):

*Topics in Algebra* by Herstein discusses Frobenius' theorem in chapter 7.

A highly-recommended standard reference for algebras is *Associative Algebras* by Pierce, but this book probably has much more material than you need or want. Frobenius' theorem appears in chapter 13.